# Java coding for arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create an array whose data is input while executing, and to show the highest value and its frequency. Also the frequencies of all the other values input.My code is correct up to the part when i input the values. Help anyone with the other part?

Comment: Show us sample of your code, that will help us to provide some help

Comment: Can you explain more with some sample code

Comment: Why can't  I submit my code? I don't understand where to put spaces in the code :/

Comment: @Peni [Help page: code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what your are asking for. The code itself is pretty straight forward.

You can also replace the highest counter with highest index... but your choice :)

```
// This is the part you already implemented...
int[] array = {10, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 32, 123, 2, 32, 32, 32, 1, 23, 123};

// Get Highest
int highest = array[0];
int highestCounter = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > highest) {
        highest = array[i];
        highestCounter = 1;
    } else if (array[i] == highest) {
        highestCounter++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Highest = " + highest);
System.out.println("Highest Frequencies = " + highestCounter);

// Get frequencies 
int[] freqArray = new int[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < freqArray.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j]) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    freqArray[i] = counter;
}

// Finally display result
for (int i = 0; i < freqArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(array[i] + " = " + freqArray[i]);
}
```

EDIT: The code below does the same, but this time it stores the index position of the highest value. Also the code is now placed in function, which will really help you if need to reuse the it again :)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] array = {10,2,2,3,5,6,1,32,123,2,32,32,32,1,23,123};

    int highestIndex = getHighestIndex(array);
    int[] frequencies = createFrequencyArray(array);

    System.out.println("Highest = " + array[highestIndex]);
    System.out.println("Highest value frequency " + frequencies[highestIndex]);

    // Finally display result
    for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i] + " frequency " + frequencies[i]);
    }

}

public static int getHighestIndex(final int[] array) {
    // Assume the highest value is at position 1
    int highestIndex = 0;

    // Ensure the array has values
    if (array.length > 0) {
        // No need to check 1 again, thus start from position 2 or array[1]
        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[highestIndex]) {
                highestIndex = i;
            } 
        }
    } else {
        highestIndex = -1;
    }

    return highestIndex;
}

public static int[] createFrequencyArray(final int[] array) {
    int[] frequencies = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < frequencies.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        frequencies[i] = counter;
    }

    return frequencies;
}
```